# HTML meta http-equiv not showing up

Tags: html, http, http-headers

I'm a little bit confused, because the HTTP header I'm trying to set is not showing up when I try to inspect the HTTP response headers with `curl` or Chromes developer tools.

I set the following header(s):

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="the_name=some_value; path=/" />
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello World.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to set the following header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=http://www.example.com" />
```

If I set a header with `PHP`, it shows up:

```
<head>
  <?php header("refresh:2; URL=site.php"); ?>
</head>
```

Why do the HTTP headers I try to set via HTML do not show up with `curl -I` or with Chrome's developer tools, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http-equiv` tries to be **equivalent** to an HTTP header, it is not a way to set a **real** HTTP header.

- Since it isn't a real HTTP header so won't show up if you look at the real HTTP headers.
- It isn't really equivalent, there are many limitations
- `set-cookie` is not a valid value for `http-equiv`

Comment: I did not knew that, I thought they were real headers. So why use the http-equivalents then? If the do not appear in HTTP, who will be interested in them, then?

Comment: I can't think of any reason to use `http-equiv`, ever.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the tools to try this out at this second, but try changing the end of the tags to the proper version.

XML:

```
" />
```

HTML:

```
 ">
```

Comment: The XML-style self-closing element syntax is permitted in HTML 5.